# 31P-13C coupling in bis(diphenylphosphino)methane

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

In the 13C NMR spectrum of bis(diphenylphosphino)methane (dppm), some of the phenyl carbon signals appear to be split into triplets. It makes sense to me that the center methylene is split into a triplet, but why would any of the phenyl C signals be triplets? I expected to see doublets.

You can see the 13C NMR of dppm here: https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/deepweb/assets/sigmaaldrich/quality/spectra/293/067/FNMR000746.pdf or

In contrast, the 13C NMR of diphenylmethylphosphine only exhibits doublets in: https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/deepweb/assets/sigmaaldrich/quality/spectra/313/648/FNMR004111.pdf

Comment: Suggest to edit the question: 1) put chemical structure and corresponding spectrum either in one illustration altogether, or at least next to each other.  2) Seek 13C NMR spectra recorded at a higher Larmour frequency (e.g. 13C 100 MHz, or better) with Reaxys, or Scifinder, or a spectroscopy database.  For 13C-31P coupling, the Aldrich spectra from the catalogue of chemicals sold is not well suitable (fix interval, no zoom into the regions of interest). 3) Shapes of theoretical spectra need not manifest in experimental ones (e.g., lack of recording resolution, applied field strength, etc.).